# Error in regex hyphen usage inside brackets utilizing perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have this perl script that compares two arrays to give me back those results found in both of them. The problem arises I believe in a regular expression, where it encounters a hyphen ( - ) inside of brackets [].

I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid [] range "5-3" in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/>gi|403163623|ref|XP_003323683.2| leucyl-tRNA synthetase [Puccinia graminis f. sp. tritici CRL 75-3 <-- HERE 6-700-3]
MAQSTPSSIQELMDKKQKEATLDMGGNFTKRDDLIRYEKEAQEKWANSNIFQTDSPYIENPELKDLSGEE
LREKYPKFFGTFPYPYMNGSLHLGHAFTISKIEFAVGFERMRGRRALFPVGWHATGMPIKSASDKIIREL
EQFGQDLSKFDSQSNPMIETNEDKSATEPTTASESQDKSKAKKGKIQAKSTGLQYQFQIMESIGVSRTDI
PKFADPQYWLQYFPPIAKNDLNAFGARVDWRRSFITTDINPYYDAFVRWQMNRLKEKGYVKFGERYTIYS
PKDGQPCMDHDRSSGERLGSQEYTCLKMKVLEWGPQAGDLAAKLGGKDVFFV at comparer line 21, <NUC> chunk 168.
```

I thought the error could be solved by just adding `\Q..\E` in the regex so as to bypass the [] but this has not worked. Here is my code, and thanks in advance for any and all help that you may offer.

```
@cyt = <CYT>;
@nuc = <NUC>;

$cyt = join ('',@cyt);
$cyt =~ /\[([^\]]+)\]/g;

@shared = '';

foreach $nuc (@nuc) {
    if ($cyt =~ $nuc) {
        push @shared, $nuc;     
    }
}

print @shared;
```

What I am trying to achieve with this code is compare two different lists loaded into the arrays @cyt and @nuc. I then compare the name in between the [] of one of the elements in list to to the name in [] of the other. All those finds are then pushed into @shared. Hope that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: There is no `\Q ... \E` in the regex with the error, only in the regex with meta characters, which is completely backwards. Do you really know what `\Q...\E` does? It escapes meta characters, so that `([^\]]+)\]` matches the literal characters, not "any character but `]`"

Comment: I see, so how would i go to escaping the - in my text files so as to not have this error? Modifying the regex to include hyphens in a greedy way?

Comment: Are you sure you want to match `$nuc` as a substring of `$cyt`? Also, you are performing a match on `$cyt` and discard the return value. Your code is all over the place, so you should state what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TLP clarified it a bit, just comparing the name in between the [] to see if it is found in the other list, and if it is, push to a new array list. I want the returned values to be found in both lists. Thank you for your insight and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question describes a *set intersection*, which is [covered in the Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays?-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays?).

> #### How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?
>
> Use a hash. Here's code to do both and more. It assumes that each
>   element is unique in a given array:
>
> ```
> my (@union, @intersection, @difference);
> my %count = ();
> foreach my $element (@array1, @array2) { $count{$element}++ }
> foreach my $element (keys %count) {
>   push @union, $element;
>   push @{ $count{$element} > 1 ? \@intersection : \@difference }, $element;
> }
> ```
>
> Note that this is the symmetric difference, that is, all elements in
>   either A or in B but not in both. Think of it as an xor operation.

Applying it to your problem gives the code below.

Factor out the common code to find the names in the data files. This sub assumes that

- every [name] will be entirely contained within a given line rather than crossing a newline boundary
- each line of input will contain at most one [name]

If these assumptions are invalid, please provide more representative samples of your inputs.

Note the use of the `/x` regex switch that tells the regex parser to ignore most whitespace in patterns. In the code below, this permits visual separation between the brackets that are delimiters and the brackets surrounding the character class that captures names.

```
sub extract_names {
  my($fh) = @_;

  my %name;
  while (<$fh>) {
    ++$name{$1} if /\[   ([^\]]+)   \]/x;
  }

  %name;
}
```

Your question uses old-fashioned typeglob filehandles. Note that the paramter `extract_names` expects is a filehandle. Convenient parameter passing is one of many benefits of indirect filehandles, such as those created below.

```
open my $cyt, "<", "cyt.dat" or die "$0: open: $!";
open my $nuc, "<", "nuc.dat" or die "$0: open: $!";

my %cyt = extract_names $cyt;
my %nuc = extract_names $nuc;
```

With the names from `cyt.dat` in the hash `%cyt` and likewise for `nuc.dat` and `%nuc`, the code here iterates over the keys of both hashes and increments the corresponding keys in `%shared`.

```
my %shared;
for (keys %cyt, keys %nuc) {
  ++$shared{$_};
}
```

At this point, `%shared` represents a *set union* of the names in `cyt.dat` and `nuc.dat`. That is, `%shared` contains all keys from either `%cyt` or `%nuc`. To compute the set difference, we observe that the value in `%shared` for a key present in both inputs must be greater than one.

The final pass below iterates over the keys in sorted order (because hash keys are stored internally in an undefined order). For truly shared keys (*i.e.*, those whose values are greater than one), the code prints them and deletes the rest.

```
for (sort keys %shared) {
  if ($shared{$_} > 1) {
    print $_, "\n";
  }
  else {
    delete $shared{$_};
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try this but the main problem I'm having would be the how to disable the hyphen error i'm getting. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Tried this but I need it to return the entire sequence  as long as it matches for [name] in both arrays. I don't want it to match everything, just match what is in between the [] but return everything. Many thanks for all your help, it is a step in the right direction.

Comment: @Gyler I believe I understand now what you want to do. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help and patience, This is a very unique and precise way of getting the results. Again, thank you!

Comment: Howdy Greg, one quick question, what would i need to modify for this list to return those arrays that do not match. Right now it shows those names that are the same in both lists. Can it also give me all those that do not match?

Comment: @Gyler The code above discards with `delete` the names that do not match. One approach is to swap the branches.

Comment: The simplest answer is usually the easiest, thanks again Greg, you are a lifesaver. Slowly learning my way up the ranks :D